# get the percentage of all values in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame such as:

```
      pt    car     walk    bike
EO    19221 15442   12932   1489
EW    19025 15484   12979   1494
Inc   21568 13650   12590   1276
Inc2  21705 13499   12608   1272
```

I want to have a percentage of whole values.
Desired results is(I have calculated it with excel):

```
       pt       car     walk    bike
EO     79.58    11.96   7.79    0.66
EW     78.65    12.28   8.63    0.44
Inc    82.22    8.78    8.23    0.77
Inc2   79.47    10.98   9.00    0.55
```

Comment: Please exlain how you get from the input to the result. It is unclear what you mean with 'percentage of whole values'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC use:

```
df = df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0).mul(100)
print (df)
             pt        car       walk      bike
EO    39.159400  31.460354  26.346671  3.033575
EW    38.840799  31.611612  26.497489  3.050100
Inc   43.940999  27.809469  25.649906  2.599625
Inc2  44.220112  27.501834  25.686578  2.591476
```